# sqlalchemy FOR UPDATE NOWAIT

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, select-for-update

The [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_lockmode) for sqlalchemy says that you can specify "FOR UPDATE NOWAIT" in PostgreSQL 8.1 upwards using Query.with_lockmode('update_nowait'). Does anyone know how to get it to add the FOR UPDATE NOWAIT instead of just FOR UPDATE?

```
PostgreSQL 9.1.6

query = db.session.query(MyTable)\
    .filter_by(process_status="PENDING")\
    .order_by(MyTable.id)\
    .with_lockmode('update_nowait')\

print query
```

sql:

```
SELECT 
MyTable.id AS MyTable_id
,MyTable.created_on AS MyTable_created_on
FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyTable.process_status = :process_status_1 
ORDER BY MyTable.id 
FOR UPDATE
```

Comment: Can you show your engine dialect?

Comment: Please try to execute this query with engine echo=True and check stdout for actual query and post it here.

Comment: The engine dialect is "postgresql". Executing the query with engine echo=True showed FOR UPDATE NOWAIT. It is good to know that the string representation of the query object isn't what actually gets executed. That will save me a lot of confusion. I hope that gets fixed someday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce similar case with Oracle 11g and SQLAlchemy 0.8.0b2.

```
db = create_engine('...',echo=True)
...
q = session.query(CauseCode.__table__).with_lockmode('update_nowait')
print q
>>>SELECT ... FROM cause_code FOR UPDATE
print renderquery(q)
>>>SELECT ... FROM cause_code FOR UPDATE NOWAIT
q.all()
>>>2013-01-23 09:58:12,665 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT ... FROM cause_code FOR UPDATE NOWAIT
```

Usually default query renderer used by **str**() produce query different from the actual query executed to DB.
I suspect that sqlalchemy behave in the same way for Postgres in your case - print q produce dialect agnostic query.

PS renderquery() method implementation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9898141/1296661)

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of sqlalchmey, you can use

```
session.query().with_for_update(of=[fields to update], nowait=True)
```