# Sqlalchemy Inheritenance - Returning zero results rawsql in psql works just fine

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In my application I have a contact_types table that is subclassed into vendor / customer contact types. A contact type is kind of like their title but not always. At any rate each of the below classes are in three different files. a globals.py file for the parent and the two children are in an customer.py and a vendor.py file.  I also used the function i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631078/sqlalchemy-print-the-actual-query) to print the actual db query with the values so that i can manually run the sql.

```
class ContactType(DeclarativeBase,TimeUserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'contact_types'
    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    _code = Column('code',Unicode(50),nullable=False)
    sort_order = Column(Integer,nullable=False,default=9999)
    type = Column(Unicode(1),nullable=False)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on':type}

    @hybrid_property  
    def code(self):
        return self._code

    @code.setter
    def code(self,code):
        self._code = code.upper()

    def __init__(self,code,sort_order=None):
        self.code=code
        if sort_order is not None:
            self.sort_order = sort_order

    @property
    def as_dict(self):
        return {
            'id':self.id,
            'code':self.code
        }

    @classmethod
    def all_as_dict(cls, ):
        return [c.as_dict for c in DBSession.query(cls).order_by(cls.code)]

    @classmethod
    def by_id(cls,id):
        return DBSession.query(cls).get(id)

    @classmethod
    def by_code(cls,code ):
        return DBSession.query(cls).filter(cls.code == code.upper()).first()

class VendorContactType(m_globals.ContactType):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'v'}

class CustomerContactType(g.ContactType):
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'c'}


Table detail ...
 create_time    | timestamp without time zone | not null
 modify_time    | timestamp without time zone | not null
 id             | integer                     | not null default nextval('contact_types_id_seq'::regclass)
 code           | character varying(50)       | not null
 sort_order     | integer                     | not null
 type           | character varying(1)        | not null
 create_user_id | integer                     | not null
 modify_user_id | integer                     | not null
Indexes:
"contact_types_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"ix_contact_types_create_user_id" btree (create_user_id)
"ix_contact_types_modify_user_id" btree (modify_user_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
"contact_types_create_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (create_user_id) REFERENCES tg_user(user_id)
"contact_types_modify_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (modify_user_id) REFERENCES tg_user(user_id)
Referenced by:
TABLE "contacts" CONSTRAINT "contacts_contact_type_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (contact_type_id) REFERENCES contact_types(id)

select id,code,type from contact_types where code='NEW';
  id  | code | type
------+------+------
 7242 | NEW  | c
 7251 | NEW  | v
```

The problem is now matter what i do the application says it can't find the record, when i copy and paste the sql used by sqlalchemy into postgres i get a result. It's maddening!!!! I am guessing there is something weird going on with the inheritance but i just can't find it.

Here's the console output i get ...

```
08:34:17,419 DEBUG [erp.model.m_ap] 0  <----- This is just a simple queryresult.count()
08:34:17,421 DEBUG [erp.model.m_ap] SELECT contact_types.code, contact_types.create_time,   contact_types.modify_time, contact_types.id, contact_types.sort_order, contact_types.type,   contact_types.create_user_id, contact_types.modify_user_id
FROM contact_types
WHERE contact_types.code = 'NEW' AND contact_types.type IN ('v') <--- output of printquery
```

So no result found. Now i will paste the query that is outputted above directly into psql ...

```
erp_beta=# SELECT contact_types.code, contact_types.create_time,   contact_types.modify_time,  contact_types.id, contact_types.sort_order, contact_types.type,   contact_types.create_user_id, contact_types.modify_user_id
erp_beta-#     FROM contact_types
erp_beta-#     WHERE contact_types.code = 'NEW' AND contact_types.type IN ('v')
erp_beta-# ;
 code |        create_time         |        modify_time        |  id  | sort_order | type | create_user_id | modify_user_id
------+----------------------------+---------------------------+------+------------+------+----------------+----------------
 NEW  | 2013-04-10 08:16:02.778212 | 2013-04-10 08:16:02.77822 | 7251 |          9 | v    |             46 |             46
(1 row)
```

What gives?

Comment: check what database and schema each is hitting.

Comment: Its the same database and scheme and just to be overly paranoid about it i added some new data to the same database for a different table and the same application displayed the new data without issue. Good thought though as we do have a couple of the "same" databases at different levels with the app (testing,beta,a local testing copy). So same database same scheme.

Comment: This is probably an insulting question(but hey, I've done it too), but is your psql session commited? Was this row added through sqlalchemy or some other way?

Comment: Not insulting at all! The data was added through sqlalchemy and it was added awhile ago.

Comment: If you add another row with sqlalchemy and try to retrieve it back can you see it?

Comment: to really be sure i changed the by_code method to loop and display all the records from the table before retrieving the specified contact type. Now the model when called from one of my controllers returns different results then from the other. So you are correct that seems to be the issue. I am using turbogears 2 and i wouldn't know how to do this if i wanted to do it on purpose. Any suggestion on how to trace this back to the cause? The app starts from a single ini file that has a single database defined.

Comment: Short answer i am mentally challenged. The controller method that calls this is actually removing all the contact types, importing them from another location, then trying to find the contact type (that has now been deleted) and then rolling back because of the error. I was digging in the wrong place. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was session related. Some code was wiping the table, importing a bunch for rows, then trying to find a row that it previously deleted. Session rolled back, and the physical database table looked the same, unchanged.