# Insert a list of dictionary using sqlalchemy efficiently

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlalchemy

I have a list containing dictionaries as elements. All the dictionaries confronts to my schema, is there a simple or efficient way to insert these details in db with sqlalchemy?

my list is below

```
[{id:'12',name:'a':lang:'eng},{id:'13',name:'b':lang:'eng},{id:'14',name:'c':lang:'eng}]
```

and I am having a schema given below

```
id String(10)
name String(10)
lang String(10)
```

Comment: See [`Executing Multiple Statements`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html#executing-multiple-statements) part of the official documentation

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As stated in [SQLAchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html#executing-multiple-statements), you can insert many records in your `table` by calling your `connection.execute()` method, using `table.insert()`  and your list of records as it's parameters, like this:

```py
connection.execute(table.insert(), [ 
        {'id':'12','name':'a','lang':'eng'},
        {'id':'13','name':'b','lang':'eng'},
        {'id':'14','name':'c','lang':'eng'},
    ]
)
```

Assuming, of course, that your `table` really has those column names as stated in your dictionary's keys and your values doesn't violate any constraint that you might have defined.

Comment: Where does the "table.insert()" come from? I surely cannot just write my database table name there??? When I try I fail.

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt, you need a table object. If you are just working with on table in your DB, you can autoload the attrs of that table with  `metadata = sa.MetaData()`
`table=sa.Table('some_table', metadata,autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)`

Comment: Can this be rewritten to the format `INSERT INTO table (id, name, lang) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
(('12, 'a', 'eng'),('13,'b','eng'),('14','c','eng')) COMMIT`? If so, how would this work?

Comment: In case someone is using [`sqlmodel`](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com), the syntax would be `connection.execute(Table.__table__.insert, dict_values)`

Answer (score 8):

An alternative use using SqlAlchemy Sessions:

```
obj_list = []
data_list = [{id:'12',name:'a':lang:'eng},{id:'13',name:'b':lang:'eng'}{id:'14',name:'c':lang:'eng}

# Loop through each object in the list
for record in data_list:
  data_obj= Table(**record)
  obj_list.append(data_obj)

session.add_all(obj_list)
session.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, not requiring to load the metadata from the database, see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/dbapi_transactions.html#sending-multiple-parameters

```
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(
        text("INSERT INTO some_table (x, y) VALUES (:x, :y)"),
        [{"x": 11, "y": 12}, {"x": 13, "y": 14}],
    )
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Interesting. What SQL query will this produce?

Comment: I imagine something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/45551136/5599687, maybe a sequence of statements.

Answer (score 0):

There is another optimize way with SQLAlchemy Core to insert a Python Dict directly into the database without using the `for` cycle.
See: [Optimize Inserts Using SQLAlchemy](https://www.devx.com/database-development-zone/optimize-inserts-using-sqlalchemy/)

```
session.execute(Table.__table__.insert(), dict_values))
session.commit()
```

`dict_values` is a Python Dict with the keys named exactly as the data base column  or a list of dicts.