# SQLAlchemy Log not writing final string

Tags: mysql, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to record the sql executed (using `echo=True`) so that I can then import that file directly (after a bit of clean-up). Problem is, the file is full of this:

```
INSERT INTO professors (department_id, id, first_name, last_name, 
    preferred_name, email_alias, user_id, created_at, updated_at, middle_name) 
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
```

So clearly, it's not giving me the final form of the string which I need.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions has two parts to it:

- The first part is answered here: [SQLAlchemy: print the actual query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631078/sqlalchemy-print-the-actual-query). *In this respect your question is a clear duplicate.*

  > Read also [How do I render SQL expressions as strings, possibly with bound parameters inlined?](http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/sqlexpressions.html#how-do-i-render-sql-expressions-as-strings-possibly-with-bound-parameters-inlined) section of the official documentation.
- The second part is: How do I make SQLAlchemy's `logging` configuration (`sqlalchemy.engine` logger) log queries using the above.

Short answer to the second part is: you cannot without tempering with the source code. See this [start line](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/50b7e818c232ecc483aced34e374074eb8a6ff16/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py?at=master#cl-1096) in the repository if you decide to play with it.