# Sqlalchemy - how to get raw sql from insert(), update() statements with binded params?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Example:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column, update, insert
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = "test"

    a = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b = Column(Integer)


update_stmt = update(Test).where(Test.a == 1).values(b=2)
print update_stmt.compile(dialect=mysql.dialect(), compile_kwargs=  {"literal_binds": True})

insert_stmt = insert(Test).values(a=1, b=1)
print insert_stmt.compile(dialect=mysql.dialect())
```

Result of this is:

```
UPDATE test SET b=%s WHERE test.a = %s
INSERT INTO test (a, b) VALUES (%s, %s)
```

The question is how to make sqlalchemy generate smth like this:

```
UPDATE test SET b=2 WHERE test.a = 1
INSERT INTO test (a, b) VALUES (1, 1)
```

For `select`, `compile_kwargs=  {"literal_binds": True}` solves the issue, but it doesn't work for `update`, `insert`.

Thanks for any help.

P.S. I need to build raw sql queries from orm, so any suggestions of any other orms, that have easy way to generate raw sql, are welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLAlchemy: print the actual query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631078/sqlalchemy-print-the-actual-query)

Comment: try putting it in quotes?

Comment: See SQLAlchemy FAQ: [How do I render SQL expressions as strings, possibly with bound parameters inlined?](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/faq/sqlexpressions.html#how-do-i-render-sql-expressions-as-strings-possibly-with-bound-parameters-inlined). You should use `literal_binds=True`.

Comment: `literal_binds` is ok for `select`, but it doesn't work for `insert`, `update`.

Comment: @tk111 did you come up with a solution?

Comment: @m79lkm unfortunatelly, no solution so far in sqlachemy aspect; I switched to http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/, it does exactly what i need.

Answer (score 4):

The solution using *compile_kwargs* -- as advertised elsewhere -- works only partially, i.e. for simple data types like Integer or String (as of SQLAlchemy v1.1.6).

```
+-------------+----------------+--------+---------------+----------+
| SQA version | compile_kwargs | SELECT | INSERT/UPDATE | datetime |
+=============+================+========+===============+==========+
| 0.7.9       |       --       |    --  |        --     |    --    |
+-------------+----------------+--------+---------------+----------+
| 0.9.4       |       √        |   1/2  |        --     |    --    |
+-------------+----------------+--------+---------------+----------+
| 1.0.11      |       √        |    √   |        --     |    --    |
+-------------+----------------+--------+---------------+----------+
| 1.0.13      |       √        |    √   |       1/2     |    --    |
+-------------+----------------+--------+---------------+----------+
| 1.1.6       |       √        |    √   |       1/2     |    --    |
+-------------+----------------+--------+---------------+----------+
```

Depending on requirements and restrictions, the following solutions will do the job:

- If you can use SQLAlchemy **v1.0.13** or above, the simplest solution is provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5698357/2127439). The *LiteralDialect* class presented there is still needed to provide correct quoting of data types like datetime. Although it is not complete, adding missing data types is very straightforward. And unfortunately you have to fix `None` to `null()` for INSERT/UPDATE.
- If you can use SQLAlchemy **v1.0.11** and need **only SELECT** statements (**not INSERT/UPDATE**), you can also use the solution from [the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5698357/2127439). SQLAlchemy v1.0.11 is distributed with ubuntu 16.04 xenial, the current LTS version (as of Mar 2017).

If you are stuck with some older version of SQLAlchemy, there is no sweet and simple approach to the problem.

So I came up with [some code supporting SQL compilation](http://sw-amt.ws/python/_build/html/sqlax.html) of queries (SELECT) as well as INSERT and UPDATE statements. The code works with SQLAlchemy **v0.7.9 - v1.1.6** and Python2/Python3.

A [detailed (and hilarious) analysis of the various features](http://sw-amt.ws/python/_build/html/sqlax.html#sql_statements_test.test_direct_compilation) is included as doctest.

The relevant code sections are:

- function [sql_statement](http://sw-amt.ws/python/_build/html/_modules/sql_statements.html#sql_statement)
- class [LiteralDialect](http://sw-amt.ws/python/_build/html/_modules/sql_statements.html#LiteralDialect)
- functions [fix_null_params](http://sw-amt.ws/python/_build/html/_modules/sql_statements.html#fix_null_params), [fix_null_values](http://sw-amt.ws/python/_build/html/_modules/sql_statements.html#fix_null_values), [null_if_none](http://sw-amt.ws/python/_build/html/_modules/sql_statements.html#null_if_none)
- variable [COMPILE_KWARGS](http://sw-amt.ws/python/_build/html/sql_statement.html#sql_statements.COMPILE_KWARGS)
- and as a bonus [table_sql_dump](http://sw-amt.ws/python/_build/html/sql_statement.html#sql_statements.table_dump_sql)

Comment: Great work. Unfortunately I'm currently not sure how to implement a literal quoting for further data types. In my case I'm running into a TypeError when trying to literalize statements (against a MySQL database) that include where clauses referencing columns with the *enum* data type: *__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '_enums'* is the corresponding message. I suppose I have to define a conversion to literal values for this type, yet I don't know how.

Comment: @le_affan SQLAlchemy v1.2.9 introduces a new keyword argument _enums, which causes the TypeError in StringLiteral for Enum. I have prepared a new version 0.2, at the same site above.

Answer (score 2):

I just run this snippet on `python 2.7` and `SQLAlchemy (1.0.13)` and it worked.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column, update, insert
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = "test"

    a = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b = Column(Integer)


update_stmt = update(Test).where(Test.a == 1).values(b=2)
print update_stmt.compile(dialect=mysql.dialect(), compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})

insert_stmt = insert(Test).values(a=1, b=1)
print insert_stmt.compile(dialect=mysql.dialect(), compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})
```

my output is:

```
UPDATE test SET b=2 WHERE test.a = 1
INSERT INTO test (a, b) VALUES (1, 1)
```

Maybe something is wrong with your environment?

Comment: It does not work with slqlalchemy v1.0.11, which ships with ubuntu 16.04 xenial.

Comment: And it fails, as soon as you use a datetime.datetime value: NotImplementedError: Don't know how to literal-quote value datetime.date(2016, 10, 3)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as complete of an answer as above. I would recommend the approach linked by wolfmanx and others.

I used this shortcut which fit my use-case. If it fails compiling with literal binds due to some unsupported type like datetime or UUID, then manually converting the values to strings works.

I just used the `.compile` method which exposed the binds.

```py
try:
    sql = str(query.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect(), compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True}))
except NotImplementedError:
    # This has special types which cannot be converted to string automatically.
    compiler = query.compile()
    variables = {key: str(value.value) for key, value in compiler.binds.items() if not key.startswith('%')}
    sql = str(query)
    # Manually replace the variables in the sql statement with their values.
    # This won't perfectly match the original statement, as this converts everything to str and wraps in double-quotes for simplicity.
    for variable, value in variables.items():
        # Variables are prefixed with :
        # Example: "DELETE FROM table WHERE skill.id = :id_1"
        sql = sql.replace(f':{variable}', f'"{value}"')
```