# How to get raw sql from session.add() in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992092/sqlalchemy-how-to-get-raw-sql-from-insert-update-statements-with-binded-p) is the answer for getting raw sql from insert and I am wondering whether I can get raw sql if I use `session.add()` such as:

```
session.add(ormclass).compile()
```

Answer (score 2):

My temporal solution to this is that when an error happens, there will be an exception and in this exception there are the parameters and statement.

```
except Exception as inst:
    print(inst.statement % inst.params)
```

But the problem still exists because I cannot get the statement and parameters if there are no exceptions. In addition, there are no quotation marks for strings in the print so the string cannot be executed in mysql directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want SQLAlchemy to log the actual raw SQL queries you can always set `echo=True` on the `create_engine` method. I know this seems rudimentary but it's the easiest way to see executed queries.

```
engine = create_engine("postgresql://localhost/dbname", echo=True)
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it returns something like: `[SQL: 'INSERT INTO '] [parameters:]` but not the raw sql.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I display the raw sql (which works most [but not all] of the time):

```
query = [my query that I created]
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql
str_query = query.compile(dialect=mysql.dialect(), compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})
```

Then I can just print the `sql_query` statement and it will show me the query with arguments. Some queries won't display, such as bulk inserts.

Comment: So do you mean that there is no way to show inserts by add?

Comment: This will show basic insert statements, but when you do bulk insert statements where it inserts more than one row at a time, it tends to not show those.