# How do I see the column names of a joined table in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I created a table using `join()`

`q = db_session.query(Email).join(Candidate)`

Is there a way to print out either the contents of `q` or the columns?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, [`.join()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) produces a new `Query` object which you can inspect via [`.column_descriptions`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.column_descriptions) and [`.statement`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.statement):

```
print(q.column_descriptions)
print(q.statement)
```

There is more to how you can inspect the query, please see:

- [SQLAlchemy: print the actual query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631078/sqlalchemy-print-the-actual-query)