# How can I print actual query generated by SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to log all SQLAlchemy queries to the console while parsing the query and filling in the parameters (e.g. translating `:param_1` to `123`). I managed to find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631078/sqlalchemy-print-the-actual-query/5698357#5698357) on SO that does just that. The issue I'm running into is that parameters don't always get translated.

Here is the event I'm latching onto -

```
@event.listens_for(Engine, 'after_execute', named=True)
def after_cursor_execute(**kw):
    conn = kw['conn']
    params = kw['params']
    result = kw['result']
    stmt = kw['clauseelement']
    multiparams = kw['multiparams']

    print(literalquery(stmt))
```

Running this query will fail to translate my parameters. Instead, I'll see `:param_1` in the output -

```
Model.query.get(123)
```

It yields a `CompileError` exception with message `Bind parameter '%(38287064 param)s' without a renderable value not allowed here.`.

However, this query will translate `:param_1` to `123` like I would expect -

```
db.session.query(Model).filter(Model.id == 123).first()
```

Is there any way to translate any and all queries that are run using SQLAlchemy?

FWIW I'm targeting SQL Server using the `pyodbc` driver.

Answer (score 1):

If you set up the logging framework, you can get the SQL statements logged by setting the sqlalchemy.engine logger at INFO level, e.g.:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Comment: Issue with this is that parameters are not inlined into the query making it difficult to copy/paste into the database without manually filling in the missing parameter placeholders.