# SQLAlchemy: print the actual raw SQL query alongside its bind params

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

well aware that something similar has been already discussed in detail ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631078/sqlalchemy-print-the-actual-query)), nevertheless my question concerns those cases in which a raw SQL must be executed.
Given the following example from S[QLAlchemy official documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql):

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.sql import text
>>> s = text(
...     "SELECT users.fullname || ', ' || addresses.email_address AS title "
...         "FROM users, addresses "
...         "WHERE users.id = addresses.user_id "
...         "AND users.name BETWEEN :x AND :y "
...         "AND (addresses.email_address LIKE :e1 "
...             "OR addresses.email_address LIKE :e2)")
>>> conn.execute(s, x='m', y='z', e1='%@aol.com', e2='%@msn.com').fetchall()
```

how can I print the actual SQL statemet with its params?

Comment: From the QA you linked to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45551136/2681632

Comment: Many thanks. After you, I figured out how to manage that problem. This question is a duplicate indeed