# SQLAlchemy: how to print real query from db session

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, backend

There are other questions similar to mine but none of them can help me find a solution. I have a query that is

```
db.session.query(cls).filter_by(id=id).delete()
```

and I'm trying to print the exact query. I have tried to following

#1

```
a = db.session.query(cls).filter_by(id=id).delete()
print str(a) # gives an error
```

#2

```
a = db.session.query(cls).filter_by(id=id).delete()
print (a.statement.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect())) # gives error like 
# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'statement'
```

#3

```
query = db.session.query(cls)
print(str(query.statement.compile(
            dialect=postgresql.dialect(),
            compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})))


# prints SELECT person_data.id, person_loc.name, person.address, person.id from person_table
   # doesn't show the id deletion in the query
```

How can I print the exact query the db session is doing during the delete?

Comment: Usually the only interesting element of a delete statement is the selection criteria, so I would print the query without the call to `.delete()`.

Answer (score 2):

The `Query.delete()` usage is executed immediately so you won't be able to print the statement.  I think the return value is the number of rows deleted so that is why you receive that `" int' object has no attribute 'statement'"`.  So **you can't print that directly other than just using echo flag**.

If you are using SQLAlchemy 1.4+ in 2.0 style you can use the [delete](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#update-and-delete-with-arbitrary-where-clause) core construct like `q = delete(cls).where(cls.id == id)` to generate the statement and then print that.  You would actually run it with `db.session.execute(q)` from that example. There are a lot of caveats to printing bound params (like `id`).

The caveats are explained in [how-do-i-render-sql-expressions-as-strings-possibly-with-bound-parameters-inlined](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/sqlexpressions.html#how-do-i-render-sql-expressions-as-strings-possibly-with-bound-parameters-inlined)

You could also use the `echo` flag to print all statements to the logs but that doesn't inline the parameters.

There is a similar question from a long time ago that now has a link to the sqlalchemy doc which I included above.  This question involves printing the special orm query `delete()` method though.

[SQLAlchemy: print the actual query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631078/sqlalchemy-print-the-actual-query)